# Angularjs performance issues in $apply, but bindings are fast

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs

I have a medium sized angular app which uses angular-1.2.10 and ui-router-0.2.8. When I transition to  a particular state I am getting frame rate issues on the animation regardless of if I am using $animate on a ng-show or manually animating it.

When I dig into the profiler I can see that the $apply after the XHR is taking up to 200ms. Which I am presuming to be the cause of the lag. When I remove the code in the state I am going to, this problem goes as expected.
[image]

There is no large ng-repeat, and the bindings are fast:
[image]

This is leaving me a bit stuck as I can't see where the issue is originating from. If anyone can see something to point me in the right direction that would be great.

UPDATE
I have done into incoginto mode and run the same tests, with the $digest counter. The $digest runs 40 times and produces the following.[image]

Lots of things seem to take a long time(30ms+) but I still can't find a cause.

UPDATE
looking at the timeline there seems to be a lot of DOMSubTreeModified.

Comment: So what is going on in the success-handler for that XHR call? It's pretty difficult to guess what the problem is just from looking at the profiler.

Comment: How much is the DOM changing? How many $digest loops are triggered?

Comment: Is their a way to count the $digest loops?

Comment: Is Batarang enabled when you are running the profiling? If so, it shouldn't be. It can slow things down significantly as it has to add code to collect its metrics.

Comment: To count $digest loops you can just do
var count = 0;
$scope.$watch(function () {
  console.log(count++)
})

Comment: The problem occurs regardless of Batarang.

Comment: Hmm, 33 times $digest runs on the state change.

Comment: Presuming this is the issue, is there a general way to reduce the number of times I enter the $digest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular uses $digest cycles to see if anything needs updating.  The pure fact that you've counted a lot is probably just another symptom of potential optimization.  The true problem lies in the time it is taking, and the processing bottleneck since it's slowing down animations.  So there are a couple of things to try:

- Make sure you are not deep-watching anything, which means you shouldn't be passing 'true' for objectEquality.  This process is more intensive and uses more memory as well.
- Use isolate scope if directives are involved - if you can.  Having an isolate scope will reduce the chatter of $digests in contrast to an inherited scope, since it will re-digest all shared scopes whenever the parent-controller changes.
- Try replacing $watch statements with an event handler if they are rendered in the DOM.  The reason for this is you can reduce the number of times the DOM is re-rendered by $broadcasting an event once the data has been processed (at the end of the XHR call) instead of it re-rendering each time you modify a property.
- Can you animate via CSS using hardware-accelerated attributes to smooth it out?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Point 1 & 4 I have already done with no success so far. I am in the process of trying point 2. With Point 3 though, I use promises to give the scope the result of the XHR, does this apply to your point about the $watches? e.g. $scope.model =  modelService.fetch($stateParams.id).$object;

Comment: $promises wouldn't change #3 necessarily.  Mileage may vary of course, but the idea is that if you know programmatically when you are done updating an object it may make more sense to notify listeners at that point rather than rely on them watching and updating as they detect changes.  Remember that bound template expressions are also $watch expressions behind the scenes.  You sound familiar with it already, but this article is a good explanation of that http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest/

Comment: Using baratang I can see the bindings are quick though. And not too many of them either. Doesn't this say that the $watches are not the issue and it might be the shear number of $digests? Does anyone have any figures on how many $digests I should expect on page load with a few XHRs?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple $digests means you have cascading model changes, where changing `a` triggers a `$watch('a')` that in turn changes `b`, which triggers another digest that might trigger a `$watch('c')`, which triggers another digest that might (heaven forbid) trigger a `$watch('a')`.

That cascade can take a long time even if each individual `$watch` evaluation is fast.  If you can do all of your changes in one go without sending them propogating between watches you'll cut down your digest count.

Comment: Is there a way to find out what caused the $digest? I don't think I have many cascades. I have a service which I used in 2 controllers, which would update itself via ajax in this case.

Comment: I also have a global controller, not sure if this would contribute to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help without the code and bindings in markup. If you have parts of UI which are read only and it doesn't depend on multiple digest cycles, try using bindonce: https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce. It might help you reduce the number of watchers and unexpected digest cycles.